# How to resolve errors related to Cython compilation of the Kivy in the Buildozer packaging of the kivy app for android 13

Tags: kivy, adb, sympy, kivymd, buildozer

I ran the following the buildozer code for the packaging a kivy app for an android environment

`!buildozer -v android debug`

I am getting the following error snippet showing a series of errors related to Cython compilation of the Kivy package

```
[INFO]:    Cythonize kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx
[DEBUG]:   -> running python3 -cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main()); ./kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx
[DEBUG]:    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx
[DEBUG]:      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
[DEBUG]:    performance hint: kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:126:5: Exception check on '_on_appsink_sample' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
[DEBUG]:    Possible solutions:
[DEBUG]:        1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
[DEBUG]:        2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.
[DEBUG]:    performance hint: kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:135:5: Exception check on '_on_gstplayer_message' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
[DEBUG]:    Possible solutions:
[DEBUG]:        1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
[DEBUG]:        2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Error compiling Cython file:
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    ...
[DEBUG]:                raise GstPlayerException('Unable to get the bus from the pipeline')
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:            gst_bus_enable_sync_message_emission(self.bus)
[DEBUG]:            if self.eos_cb or self.message_cb:
[DEBUG]:                self.hid_message = c_bus_connect_message(
[DEBUG]:                        self.bus, _on_gstplayer_message, <void *>self)
[DEBUG]:                                  ^
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:228:30: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, GstMessage *) except * nogil' to 'buscallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, GstMessage *) except * nogil'.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Error compiling Cython file:
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    ...
[DEBUG]:            # attach the callback
[DEBUG]:            # NOTE no need to create a weakref here, as we manage to grab/release
[DEBUG]:            # the reference of self in the set_sample_callback() method.
[DEBUG]:            if self.sample_cb:
[DEBUG]:                self.hid_sample = c_appsink_set_sample_callback(
[DEBUG]:                        self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
[DEBUG]:                                      ^
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:269:34: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil' to 'appcallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil'.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    Error compiling Cython file:
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    ...
[DEBUG]:            if self.appsink != NULL:
[DEBUG]:                gst_element_get_state(self.pipeline, &current_state,
[DEBUG]:                        &pending_state, <GstClockTime>GST_SECOND)
[DEBUG]:                if current_state != GST_STATE_PLAYING:
[DEBUG]:                    c_appsink_pull_preroll(
[DEBUG]:                        self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
[DEBUG]:                                      ^
[DEBUG]:    ------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:418:34: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil' to 'appcallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil'.
Exception in thread background thread for pid 42153:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx

  STDOUT:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
performance hint: kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:126:5: Exception check on '_on_appsink_sample' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
    1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
    2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.
performance hint: kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:135:5: Exception check on '_on_gstplayer_message' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
    1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
    2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            raise GstPlayerException('Unable to get the bus from the pipeline')

        gst_bus_enable_sync_message_emission(self.bus)
        if self.eos_cb or self.message_cb:
            self.hid_message = c_bus_connect_message(
                    self.bus, _on_gstplayer_message, <void *>self)
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:228:30: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, GstMessage *) except * nogil' to 'buscallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, GstMessage *) except * nogil'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        # attach the callback
        # NOTE no need to create a weakref here, as we manage to grab/release
        # the reference of self in the set_sample_callback() method.
        if self.sample_cb:
            self.hid_sample = c_appsink_set_sample_callback(
                    self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
                                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:269:34: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil' to 'appcallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        if self.appsink != NULL:
            gst_element_get_state(self.pipeline, &current_state,
                    &pending_state, <GstClockTime>GST_SECOND)
            if current_state != GST_STATE_PLAYING:
                c_appsink_pull_preroll(
                    self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
                                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:418:34: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil' to 'appcallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil'.


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1262, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 680, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 99, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 158, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1028, in build_arch
    self.build_cython_components(arch)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1053, in build_cython_components
    self.cythonize_build(env=env)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 38, in cythonize_build
    super().cythonize_build(env, build_dir=build_dir)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1101, in cythonize_build
    self.cythonize_file(env, build_dir, join(root, filename))
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/kivy/__init__.py", line 59, in cythonize_file
    super().cythonize_file(env, build_dir, filename)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 1090, in cythonize_file
    shprint(python_command, "-c"
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 '-cimport sys; from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main; sys.exit(setuptools_main());' ./kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx

  STDOUT:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:381: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/kivy/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/kivy/kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx
  tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
performance hint: kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:126:5: Exception check on '_on_appsink_sample' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
    1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
    2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.
performance hint: kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:135:5: Exception check on '_on_gstplayer_message' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
    1. Declare the function as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
    2. Use an 'int' return type on the function to allow an error code to be returned.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            raise GstPlayerException('Unable to get the bus from the pipeline')

        gst_bus_enable_sync_message_emission(self.bus)
        if self.eos_cb or self.message_cb:
            self.hid_message = c_bus_connect_message(
                    self.bus, _on_gstplayer_message, <void *>self)
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:228:30: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, GstMessage *) except * nogil' to 'buscallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, GstMessage *) except * nogil'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        # attach the callback
        # NOTE no need to create a weakref here, as we manage to grab/release
        # the reference of self in the set_sample_callback() method.
        if self.sample_cb:
            self.hid_sample = c_appsink_set_sample_callback(
                    self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
                                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:269:34: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil' to 'appcallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil'.

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        if self.appsink != NULL:
            gst_element_get_state(self.pipeline, &current_state,
                    &pending_state, <GstClockTime>GST_SECOND)
            if current_state != GST_STATE_PLAYING:
                c_appsink_pull_preroll(
                    self.appsink, _on_appsink_sample, <void *>self)
                                  ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/lib/gstplayer/_gstplayer.pyx:418:34: Cannot assign type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil' to 'appcallback_t'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (void *, int, int, char *, int) except * nogil'.


  STDERR:




# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=kdvpainlevecompatibilityapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy==2.2.1,kivymd==1.1.1,sympy=1.12,mpmath=1.3.0', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '11.11.3.6-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TRANSPORT = 'ipc'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.86-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     CGROUP_MEMORY_EVENTS = '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.events /var/colab/cgroup/jupyter-children/memory.events'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.15.5-1+cuda11.8'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.15.5-1'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.253'
#     HOSTNAME = 'd0869d5a7c84'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.8 brand=tesla,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=unknown,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=nvidia,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=nvidiartx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=geforce,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=geforcertx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=quadro,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=quadrortx,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=titan,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=titanrtx,driver>=470,driver<471')
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-11-8=11.11.3.6-1'
#     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '11.8.86-1'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_IP = '172.28.0.12'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.89-1'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '11.7.5.86-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_ROOT_URL = 'http://172.28.0.1:8013/'
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '11.8.0.86-1'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.15.5-1'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = '30s'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.9.6.50-1+cuda11.8'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TOKEN = ''
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20231120'
#     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-11-8=11.8.87-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-11-8=11.8.0.86-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
#     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.20'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '11.11.3.6-1'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_HOST = '172.28.0.12'
#     NVIDIA_PRODUCT_NAME = 'CUDA'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-11-8'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '11.8.89-1'
#     COLAB_WARMUP_DEFAULTS = '1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     COLUMNS = '100'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.8.0'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-11-8=11.11.3.6-1'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nsight-compute-11-8=11.8.0-1'
#     COLAB_RELEASE_TAG = 'release-colab_20231130-060122_RC00'
#     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     KMP_EXTRA_ARGS = ('--logtostderr --listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 '
 '--tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-3gk88z1ady4hk '
 '--tunnel_background_save_delay=10s '
 '--tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s '
 '--enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-11-8=11.8.0.86-1'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY_LSP_DIRS = '/datalab/web/pyright/typeshed-fallback/stdlib,/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-11-8'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_PORT = '6000'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.0.86-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '75'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '11.7.5.86-1'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.9.6.50'
#     SHLVL = '0'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     COLAB_LANGUAGE_SERVER_PROXY = '/usr/colab/bin/language_service'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '11.8.0-1'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.9.6.50-1+cuda11.8'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-11-8'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.15.5-1+cuda11.8'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     COLAB_GPU = ''
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_CUDA_NSIGHT_COMPUTE_VERSION = '11.8.0-1'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '11.8.87-1'
#     LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     COLAB_FILE_HANDLER_ADDR = 'localhost:3453'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     COLAB_DEBUG_ADAPTER_MUX_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.15.5-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     COLAB_BACKEND_VERSION = 'next'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

The series of my commands before this that I run are as follows:

pip3 install kivy kivymd mpmath sympy; sudo apt-get update; pip3 install --upgrade mpmath; sudo apt-get install autoconf; pip3 install --upgrade buildozer; pip3 install --upgrade sympy cython mpmath; sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2; sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libtbbbind_2_0.so.3; sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libtbbbind_2_5.so.3; sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libtbbbind.so.3; sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libtbb.so.12; sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libtbbmalloc.so.2; sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libtbbbind.so.3 /usr/lib/libtbbbind.so.3; sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libtbbmalloc.so.2 /usr/lib/libtbbmalloc.so.2; sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libtbbbind_2_5.so.3 /usr/lib/libtbbbind_2_5.so.3; sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libtbb.so.12 /usr/lib/libtbb.so.12; sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2 /usr/lib/libtbbmalloc_proxy.so.2; sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libtbbbind_2_0.so.3 /usr/lib/libtbbbind_2_0.so.3; sudo ldconfig; sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip build-essential git python3 python3-dev ffmpeg libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev      libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev; sudo apt-get install -y libgstreamer1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good; sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi7; sudo apt-get install libffi-dev; sudo apt-get install gettext; sudo apt-get install libtool; sudo apt-get install intltool; sudo apt-get install gtk-doc-tools; buildozer init

Please help; this application is almost close to a finish which is aimed at accelerating a differential geometry based computation using sympy in the backend of this Kivy app.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your Cython version is to recent to compile the Kivy code and package it in your application.

You can try to downgrade Cython to the `0.29.26` version.